# What does "first, last and deposit" mean when looking for an apartment?

Tags: terminology, rent

I was online looking for an apartment. It says, "we'll only need first, last, and deposit once your application is approved."

What does this mean?

Comment: Where are you located geographically? The legal treatment of security deposits can vary from place to place.

Comment: Note that the legality of this will depend on where you are located. In Alberta, Canada, it's only legal to ask for first month plus a security deposit less than or equal to one month of rent. No more.

Answer (score 21):

This means that once your application is approved, you'll need to pay your first and last month's rent and a [security deposit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_deposit#In_leasing). You may get your security deposit back when you terminate your lease, assuming you've met all the conditions in the lease and haven't damaged your apartment.

If you decide to extend your lease, your last month's rent is usually carried forward and applied to the last month of your new/extended lease. For example, if you lease an apartment from September 2013 through the end of September 2014, your last month's rent is assumed to apply to September 2014. If you choose to extend your lease through the end of September 2015, your last month's rent is assumed to apply to September 2015, and so on. In other words, your last month's rent applies to the last month of your lease as it's currently stated. If you change/extend the lease, the last month changes.

If your rent increases sometime over the course of your lease (or your lease extension, specifically), you'll usually owe the difference between the amount you paid for your last month and the current rent. For example, if you pay last month's rent of $1500 when you sign your lease, but the rent increases to $1800 when you extend your lease, you'll probably owe $300 in the last month.

Comment: When the lease _expires_, that is, terminates naturally, the security deposit should be returned subject to the conditions stated in John's answer. In many states, the landlord may be required to pay interest on the security deposit also. On the other hand, in cases of _early_ termination at the renter's request, that last month's rent _might_ be applied to the rent for the last month (or partial month) of actual occupation of the premises, or might be kept by the landlord as a fee for permitting early termination of the lease. All this might be spelled out in the lease document too.

Comment: @DilipSarwate All good points. I was just inquiring where the OP was located so I could find more specific information about security deposits.

Comment: Many leases are for a full year, and the monthly rate for short-term rentals is usually more than the full-year rate, because the landlord has more expenses involved -- advertising the property for rent again in just a few weeks' time, clean up and getting the apartment ready for another rental, etc.

Comment: @AndySmith Yes, in addition to the security deposit.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Outside of hot markets the LL will also likely have a time period where the apartment isn't generating any revenue. That could easily be more than the other expenses.

Comment: @DanNeely Yes, of course, that is a major factor. But, technically, it is not an _expense_ when no income is received, and for simplicity, I was just pointing out the out-of-pocket costs.

Comment: @JohnBensin - in paying the last months rent what happens if the rent goes up after a certain period?

Comment: @Victor You'll most likely owe the difference. I updated the answer with an example; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JohnBensin - I only asked because in AUS we usually pay rent weekly and you usually pay 2 weeks in advanced rent plus 4 weeks bond (security deposit). The bond actually gets lodged with a State Government body called the Rental Board. So any interest on the bond is paid to the tenant with the bond by the Rental Board after the tenant vacates, subject to there being no monies owing to the landlord.

Comment: In some jurisdictions, the "last month's rent" is legally considered to be part of the security deposit, not pre-payment of rent.  Many landlords in such jurisdictions do not understand these laws.